# "1s" command cannot be found in terminal

Tags: macos, bash

When I attempt to list a directory using the 1s command I receive the line

> -bash: 1s: command not found

Answer (score 5):

The command starts with the letter `L`, not the number `1` or the letter `I`; it's short for `list`. The font you're using may make that confusing, in which case I would suggest changing to a different fixed-width font for your terminal. I personally am a fan of `PragmataPro` and `Courier New`, and you'll find `Courier New` installed on pretty much any Windows, Linux, or OS X system these days.

If you're having trouble with the fonts on a particular website when looking up help information for commands, you can try copying and pasting the command. Note that most terminals on Windows and Linux don't usually support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for pasting unless you play with the keybindings, but OS X does support the usual <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for pasting in its Terminal.app.